# Is there a way to update or set fields like upsert does for documents?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

If I wanted to update a document if it exists, or add it if it doesn't, there's `upsert`.

But what if I want to update a field if it exists, or add it if it doesn't?

Imagine my document called `UserProfiles` looks like this from the start:

```
{
    _id: "c8fdu98JC",
    questions: []
}
```

But can also look like this if an answer is added:

```
{
    _id: "c8fdu98JC",
    questions: [{questionId: "age", answerId: "b"}]
}
```

So the user can either click an answer for the first time or change his mind and choose a different answer. Can I do an `upsert` kind of operation to update or set this field?

This,

```
UserProfiles.update({_id: userId,
    'questions.questionId': questionId},
    {$set: {'questions.$.answerId': answerId}})
```

will only update if it already exists.

Since the answer is very likely that an `upsert` kind of operation isn't available for this purpose, what would be a good way to go about this in the least costly (but still secure) way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) to add a document in an array if it doesn't exist.

However, since there is no direct equivalent to upset for array updation, you will need to take care of updating, if already exists, in your application code.

Alternatively, you can use two step operation for updation `$pull` and then `$push`. If exists it will remove it and then it will add the new data by push, otherwise, it will simply push.

Answer (score -1):

I'm doing this currently:

```
UserProfiles.update({_id: userId,
    'questions.questionId': questionId},
    {$set: {'questions.$.answerId': answerId}},
    function(error, result) {
        if (error || result === 0) {
            UserProfiles.update({_id: userId},
                {$addToSet: {questions: {questionId: questionId, answerId: answerId}}})
        }
    }
)
```

It's pretty decent, I suppose. If someone has a better way, do tell!